# Can't close model bottom sheet by click outside when isScrollControlled property true

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I'm having a modal bottom sheet, in which contain some text field. I want the bottom sheet to close when click outside of the sheet but due to isScrollControlled property is true so i cant do that.

But if i change it to false my bottom sheet will be covered by keyboard when i focus to my textfield on it. Is there any way to solve it.

This is how i create my sheet

```
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        isDismissible: true,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.circular(12))),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const BottomSheetView(); 
        });
```

here is how my sheet look
[image]

Comment: Share `BottomSheetView` code

Comment: Hello, can you send me the BottomSheetView() screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your whole widget with `GestureDetector` and `ontap` function just `Navigator.pop(context)` while enabling **isScrollControlled** property **true**

Answer (score 2):

here my article on medium: https://medium.easyread.co/my-september-flutter-notes-700907827c7f

```
Padding(padding: 
EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
child: ListView()
```

`ListView()` is all your Widget inside the `BottomSheet`
by add a padding, it will detect the onscreen keyboard, and set the widget ontop if keyboard.